# Tesseract OCR won't recognize division symbol "÷"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocr, tesseract

I am using Tesseract in iOS 8 for an OCR based app but it incorrectly converts the division "÷" symbol in the image to a plus "+" sign.

For example, this image

[image: Simple arithmetic expression]

always converts to the text string "8+4+4". It should be "8+4÷4".

I've tried using different trained data language files "eng+equ", "ita", adding "÷" to the whitelist, setting the ocr_engine variable to cube, converting image to grayscale or black & white, upsizing the image by 2 and 4 times.

Everything I've tried always returns a plus "+" sign instead of a division "÷" symbol.

I tried using only the "equ" trained data file and that DOES return the division symbol correctly - but all other characters are then garbage.

I've been looking into this (Google, Stackoverflow) for several days and cannot figure it out.

How do I get Tesseract to include and recognize the division "÷" symbol?

**UPDATE**:

The best I have been able to do is to set the AVCaptureSession preset to high

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
```

The captured image above dimensions are then 676 × 405 pixels. Using Tesseract OCR UIImage category (image is named 'source') to binarize the image:

```
// Binarize the source image to improve contrast (using the UIImage category provided by TesseractOCR)
UIImage *blackAndWhiteImage = [source blackAndWhite];
[self.tesseract setImage:blackAndWhiteImage];
```

This will usually convert the division symbol to the text "-1-", but I've seen "-:-" and other numbers and uppercase characters between the minus signs.

I can check for that in the returned text. But then it is impossible to know whether to treat the returned text "8-1-2" as a true subtraction or 'maybe' division.

Comment: Unfortunately OCR is not perfect and Tesseract specifically will "blob" together pixels that it think may be a single character, compensating for poor picture quality at the cost of precision. Essentially Tesseract cannot tell if the division symbol is a poorly-printed "+" or an actual division symbol. [Here's more reading on how Tesseract reads text](https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/git/doc/tesseracticdar2007.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Morgan. I had wondered about that but it has no problems detecting and correctly converting characters like "i j : ;".

Comment: You can try to open an issue here: https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/issues
May be here you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Train the or engine wit different fonts.

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/serak-tesseract-trainer/) is the tool for training the engine.
Have a look on [this](http://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine/) also

Or you can use [JTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your "white list" includes"÷" sign.

In swift, this will do it: `tesseract.setVariableValue("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:;,.!-()#&÷", forKey: "tessedit_char_whitelist")`

In objective-C, here is the code:

```
[tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:;,.!-()#&÷" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
```

You can customize the character set based on your needs.

Comment: I have already tried this and got the same results as not using the whitelist at all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that symbol was not included in the existing data. You'd need to [train](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract) for that symbol, and then use the resultant traineddata in combination with existing ones.

You can use a tool, such as [jTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html), to assist you in the training process.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and capture this ambiguity via the unicharambigs file. Read more 
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/unicharambigs.5.asc.

```
1       +       1      ÷    0
```

Tesseract would read it as "optionally (the trailing 0 in the above config) replace the 1 char sequence '+' with the 1 character sequence '÷'".

Comment: the link you provided was not working. can you provide any other link?

Comment: @Ramakrishna https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/unicharambigs.5.asc

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, changing `engineMode` works for me

```
let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng")!
tesseract.engineMode = .tesseractCubeCombined
```