# Detect special Unicode characters with Tesseract

Tags: c#, tesseract

At work, we have around 17000 Images of Codes, we need to check for errors. So I was told to create a program that detects these errors (For example in one of these pictures, there is a ⬜, because something went wrong when creating the image).

I am using Tesseract for C# to scan the text out of the images and want to check for such squares. I've whitelisted every uppercase letter, every number, > and <, and the ⬜-Square.

```
static string OcrDoYourThing(Image ImgPath)
{
    var imgsource = new Bitmap(ImgPath);
    var tessdata = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Images";
    var filter = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<>1234567890□⬜";

    var ocrtext = string.Empty;
    using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(tessdata, "en", EngineMode.Default))
    {
        engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", filter);

        using (var img = PixConverter.ToPix(imgsource))
        {
            using (var page = engine.Process(img))
            {
                ocrtext = page.GetText();
            }
        }
    }
    return ocrtext;
}
```

But when there is an image with such a square, Tesseract recognizes it as a "D", or "EI". 
For example the text on the image "⬜>12345ABCDE"<<<<" gets detected as "D>12345ABCDE"<<<<" or "EI>12345ABCDE"<<<<"

Is there a trained english version, that can detect these squares?

Comment: There are no "special" Unicode characters. What you posted is a subset of ASCII with a couple of symbols. ⬜ is [this character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2B1C) and *doesn't* contain images, □ is [this character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25A1) and again, it doesn't contain other images. Are you trying to make Tesseract recognise shapes as well as letters? Are you sure it *can* do that?

Comment: No, we have images of Text, where we need to extract the text. Sometimes, there can be a ⬜ in that text in the image, which we also need to detect so we can mark that image as faulty. But Tesseract can't detect the ⬜, it thinks it's a "D", or sometimes an "EI"

Comment: You're trying to make Tesseract recognise a shape as a symbol.  Different fonts will display the same symbols differently too. Did you notice hot the large white square is actually *grey* in this page? Check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956913/tesseract-ocr-wont-recognize-division-symbol-÷)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/idtUFMk
That's the square in the image